# AWS ELB Flow rate drops abnormally

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc

In the past half hour，I get two pingdom alerts like this

```
Pingdom DOWN alert:
xxxxx.com (www.xxxx.com) is down since 2020-07-15 19:49:48.
Reason: Socket timeout, unable to connect to server
```

[CloudWatch shows ELB RequestCount reduce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BzyJ.png)

All aws resources are normal
Is this a network problem?

Comment: What debug have you done so far? Have you investigated for any performance issues on you app?

Comment: I troubleshoot my system，it's healthy，and I can't find pingdom recording in nginx log

Comment: Is the ELB the first point of contact for the user, or are there other layers in front?

Comment: yes，and this problem also appears in other services